# Getting a blank page after logging into administration on non-SU account

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, acl, user-groups

I want to give certain users permission to access the administration panel, but no permission to modify things aside from that which I've specifically allowed.

I created a group called "John" in which I have added a user called "John". This group is a sub-group of the Registered Users group. I specifically have set permissions on one article for this group to edit, and I do not want that group to edit anything else.

I have allowed this group to access the administrator panel by setting the following options through the Permissions tab of Global Configuration:

- Site login: allowed
- Administrator login: allowed
- Access Administration Interface: allowed

But when I log in with John's username and password, I get this:
[image]

It is a blank page, only having the header that is in the administration panel usually, and all I can do is edit John's account details.

I have only one extension installed: BreezingForms Lite (http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/breezingforms-lite).

The administration panel works **fine** with the user I set up during Joomla installation. But it does not work for John, even when I tried giving the account Superuser permissions. It's always just a blank page.

I have the error reporting to 'maximum' in `configuration.php` but I'm not getting any errors, not even in the web server error log.

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously it is something wrong with your ACL.

Usually it's hard to give a reply with the actual solution in such questions with the first try, as ACL needs a hands-on investigation, or otherwise the complete ACL configuration, in order for someone to try to understand or replicate an issue.

But in your case, I would guess that you haven't added **Viewing Access Level** for your new usergroup.

If you have create it as child under the Registered Usergroup, then it won't inherit the Special Viewing Access Level, so users of that group can't have viewing access on elements.

So, go in **Users -> Access Levels** - and make sure you check the **Special** level for your usergroup.

*Also note, that it is recommended to logout/re-login users, after making changes on the ACL.